# Gnome - shortcut to switch through instances of one application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

I am using Ubuntu and Gnome. If I want to switch from one app to the other I can use Alt + Tab - perfect! In my current Gnome environment, one app for example Nautilus is able to start more than one instance. Alt + Tab hops over all Nautilus instances at once. What is the shortcut to switch between all 'own' instances of an app in Linux Ubuntu Gnome.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good place for questions that have nothing to do with programming. In the future, try [SU] for questions like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `Alt+Tab` to nautilus and wait 1sec (or hit down arrow) it will pop up all instances and you can "arrow navigate" them.

OR

`Alt+Tab` and when you reach to nautilus hit alt+` (key above tab)

Answer (score 0):

<Super> + ` will let you switch through all open windows of the currently active application.

If you have 3 Chrome windows open, <Super> + ` will switch through each instance regardless of what desktop or virtual desktop they are on.

This will show you all your key bindings:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -e org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings -e org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys -e org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power | sort
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990559/in-ubuntu-gnome-fedora-can-you-set-multiple-shortcut-keys-instead-of-just-a) for more info.