# In Gnome (gnome-shell) can you set multiple shortcut keys instead of just a single?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

The Gnome GUI (gnome-shell) only lets you set a single shortcut key.  Can you for instance set <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to both switch applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  This is verified to work on Ubuntu 20.10 and 21.04RC.

The following commands acheive the requested outcome:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward "['<Shift><Super>Tab', '<Shift><Alt>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Super>Tab', '<Alt>Tab']"
```

For more options see here:

```
# list all keybindings
gsettings list-recursively | grep -e org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings -e org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys -e org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power | sort 

# confirm no other keybinding conflicts
gsettings list-recursively | grep '<Control>1'

# set multiple keybindings for "Switch to Workspace 1"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 "['<Super>Home', '<Control>1']"

# confirm value is set correctly
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1
```

from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59250/assign-multiple-keyboard-shortcuts-for-one-action/1098498#1098498).

Answer (score 0):

If you want bidirectional Alt-Shift switching

Also helps:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L', '<Shift>Alt_L']"
```